# Remove white space Python writerows

Tags: python, csv

I have the following structure in a dictionary:

```
 self._results = {'key1':'1,2,3','key2':'5,6,7'}
```

I'm using `csv writerows()` to write the records from the dictionary into a file:

```
filewriter = csv.writer(
          csvfile,
          quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,
          delimiter=',',
          quotechar='',
          escapechar=' ')
      filewriter.writerows(self._results.items())
```

Unfortunately I get the following:

```
key1,1 ,2 ,3
key2,4 ,5 ,6
```

If I remove `escapechar` or change it to '' I get:

```
Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set
```

Any suggestions?

I can remove whitespaces by manipulating the CSV file afterwards, but ideally I would like to do all the text manipulation in one place.

Comment: I might be saying something terrible, but... what happens if you tell the `writer` that `escapechar=''` (empty string)?

Comment: escapechar='' returns same error as stated before, thanks for replying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You disabled quoting. So without an escape character, it can't output the commas; they'd be mistaken for field separators in the CSV format. You need to provide some sort of escape character, or allow quoting (allowing quoting with `QUOTE_MINIMAL` is the default).

If your goal was to have `1`, `2` and `3` be separate fields in the result, you shouldn't be storing them as a pre-comma separated string in the `dict`, because that's `csv`'s job, and trying to do its job for it just means fighting `csv` and risking logic errors that make it impossible to round trip the data correctly.

If they're a single logical field, allow quoting. If they're more than one field, build the `dict` as a `dict` of `list`s (`defaultdict(list)` is helpful if the values are being built piecemeal), then output a raw sequence, not partially preformatted text:

```
# Define values as lists, not strings
self._results = {'key1':[1,2,3],'key2':[5,6,7]}

# Wrap k in list and concatenate v to make four item list
filewriter.writerows([k] + v for k, v in self._results.items())
```